# What does `object Foo extends (Bar => Baz)` mean?

Tags: scala

I was reading `dispatch`'s code, and come across this [file](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/as/xml/elem.scala), in which, it says:

```
object Elem extends (Res => scala.xml.Elem) {
  def apply(res: Res) =
    XML.withSAXParser(factory.newSAXParser).loadString(res.getResponseBody)
    ...
```

What does `object Elem extends (Res => scala.xml.Elem)` mean?

Comment: This is a dupe, but it means Elem is a function, takes a Res, returns a Elem.  X => Y means Function1[X, Y].

Comment: Normally, this might be a -1, but reading code is +1, so it balances out.

Comment: @som-snytt, yep, I realized this is a bad question. I am so used to the short-hand form of anonymous function, that I forgot its complete form...:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A => B` is the syntax used to describe [anonymous functions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html).

The object declaration

```
object Elem extends (Res => scala.xml.Elem) { /* ... */ }
```

is shorthand for

```
object Elem extends Function1[Res, scala.xml.Elem] { /* ... */ }
```

In natural language: `Elem` is a function which produces a `scala.xml.Elem` object from a `Res` object.

A look at the [scaladoc for `Function1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1) shows that `Function1` declares an abstract `apply` method which is used to implement the function's logic.

Answer (score 1):

It also illustrates that [Functions are objects](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/basics2.html#fnobj)

> A Function is a set of traits. Specifically, a function that takes one argument is an instance of a `Function1` trait.
>
> Classes can also extend Function and those instances can be called with `()`.

```
scala> class AddOne extends Function1[Int, Int] {
     |   def apply(m: Int): Int = m + 1
     | }
defined class AddOne
```

> A nice short-hand for `extends Function1[Int, Int]` is `extends (Int => Int)`

```
class AddOne extends (Int => Int) {
  def apply(m: Int): Int = m + 1
}
```

And that looks like the syntax in your question.